# Needing help understanding logic in "Head First Java"

Tags: java

I have recently started programming in Java for the first time (just as a hobby), and at the moment Im working with a book "Head First Java" that is very good, but I'm really struggling with understanding the exercises.

Like this for example:

```
class Output {
    
    void go() {
        
        int y = 7;
        for(int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
            y++;                                 // is y now 8?
            if(x >4) {
                System.out.println(++y + " ");  // does this make y = 9?
            }
            if(y > 14) {
                System.out.println(" x = " + x);
                break;                       // how does the break key word affect the rest of the loop?
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Output o = new Output();
        
        o.go();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what goes on in this code?

Comment: Yes to your first two questions. `break` abruptly ends the `for` loop.

Comment: Hint: this place isnt meant as programming school were people *teach* you. And learning programming is mostly about finding out things *yourself*. So: always try to answer your question yourself first. For example: when you dont understand what your code is doing, simply add print statements all over the place. Print y before y++, and afterwards. Doing such things teaches you more about programming than other people giving you nice explanations. Asking others should be your last resort, not your first.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `y` must be 15, because you increased it's value many times with the `for` loop.

`++y` increases it's value by 1. `i++` and `++i` are very similar but not exactly the same. Both increment the number, but `++i` increments the number before the current expression is evaluted, whereas `i++` increments the number after the expression is evaluated.

`break` simply exists from the loop.